# How to create an API like Alamofire does in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In the [Alamofire.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift) file the main API functions are not nested within a class or struct:

```
import Foundation
...
public func request(method: Method, URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL) -> Request {
    return Manager.sharedInstance.request(method, URLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding)
}
```

yet they are able to be accessed as if they were a `class func` since `Alamofire.` is prepended to the function call:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post")
```

It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the fact the filename is Alamofire.swift. Is this a framework setting? I'd like to be able to do this for one of my own APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [readme](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#source-file),  `Alamofire.request` is used because you're importing the framework, so you have to specify where `request` is located.

When not using a framework, and importing the .swift files directly, it states:

> Additionally, any of the calling conventions described in the 'Usage'
>   section with 
>       the  Alamofire  prefix would instead omit it (for example,  Alamofire.request  becomes
>       request ), since this functionality is incorporated into the top-level namespace.

So to answer your question, to get your own API to use a prefix such as Alamofire, you need to create a framework an `import` it into your project.